# Unable to install plugins in Nuxt JS 3

Tags: npm, plugins, nuxtjs3

I am a React JS Developer learning Nuxt JS - But I am failing to understand the way NPM libreries are imported and used in Nuxt 3 as plugins.

**Console:**

```
Failed to resolve import "C:/Users/Eigenaar/Desktop/nuxt- 
course/first/plugins/v-tooltip.js" from 
"virtual:nuxt:C\.....first\.nuxt\plugins\client.mjs"
```

**plugins/test.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VTooltip from 'v-tooltip'
Vue.use(VTooltip)
```

**nuxt.config.ts**

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
modules: [
'@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'
],

plugins: ['~/plugins/v-tooltip.js'],
})
```

**app.vue**

```
   <h2 v-tooltip="Show tooltip">Hover me!!</h2>
```

**I have been following the official documentation but still getting error messages when trying to use third party NPM packages in general, is anybody having the same issue?**

Comment: To define nuxt plugins, you have to use `defineNuxtPlugin`. To define vue plugin, refer to the documentation: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins#vue-plugins. However, is v-tooltip compatible with vue 3 ?

Comment: Thanks, that definitely helped - I now get a new error on screen:

500
Cannot call a class as a function -

And in console:

 Hydration node mismatch:
- Client vnode: div 
- Server rendered DOM: <!--[--> (start of fragment) 
  at <ErrorDev statusCode=500 statusMessage="Internal Server Error" description="Cannot call a class as a function"  ... >   Any idea?